# Wordpress post guid doesn't change after changing to a new domain name

Tags: wordpress, guid

I'm currently doing some testing on wordpress.

In a recent test I found out that when changing the site url in the settings menu from domain a, to domain b.

In the actual mysql table, the guid attribute in the posts table doesnt change.

example:
site created on url: http://10.0.0.31/wptest1, original GUID example:
http://10.0.0.31/wptest1/?p=1

changed to: http://wptest1.com/wptest1, GUID is unchanged: http://10.0.0.31/wptest1/?p=1

We are afraid that this could cause trouble in the future and my boss and I are agreeing that this would be a major bug.

My question is: What is the GUID used for and why is it unchanged after changing the main url.

So far we havn't found any issues on the user side, but if plugins were to use the guid then we're going to run into problems...

I hope you guys can help.

Grtz, Thomas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a bug. It is by design. GUIDs are only used as an internal *globally unique* identifier for a post. Users should never see them. See [Important GUID note](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Important_GUID_Note) for more info.

Comment: It says "NEVER" change the GUID, but then directly under it, they say it's okay to change the GUID of attachment-posts. Seems a bit vague if it was important enough to write in bold text *twice* that the GUID should never change.

Comment: @Mikepote You are referring to the *"If the default uploads folder needs to be changed to a different location, then any media URLs will need to be changed in the post_content column of the posts table."* part? It might be confusing that it is written in the same section, but as far as I can see it doesn't entail changing the GUID.

Comment: @Magne It was a long time ago when I wrote that, the documentation seems to have been updated since...